# jQuery Drag and Drop not working in FireFox

Tags: jquery, math, random, drag-and-drop

I'm creating a math game. The game will allow children to drag the subtraction symbol "-" over any of the two numbers and the answer will appear (e.g. 9-4 = 5).

The code below does work properly on Chrome and Safari but the drag functionality does NOT work on Firefox.

Can anyone suggest ways to optimize the code below and make the drag functionality work on Firefox?

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/W572n/

Thanks in Advance

```
(function(){

    //declare my variables
    var numLow = 1, //lowest number
        numHigh = 20,//highest number
        $firstNum = $('#firstNum'),
        $secondNum = $('#secondNum'),
        adjustedHigh, numRand1, numRand2 = null;


        //Callback function when cancelling the event
        function cancel(e){
            if(e.preventDefault){
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            return false;
        }

        //generates random numbers and stores random numbers in data-price attribute 
        //and displays random numbers in divs #firstNum and #secondNum
        adjustedHigh = (parseFloat(numHigh) - parseFloat(numLow)) + 1;

        numRand1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*adjustedHigh) + parseFloat(numLow);

        numRand2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*adjustedHigh) + parseFloat(numLow);

        $firstNum.attr('data-price', numRand1);

        $firstNum.text( $("#firstNum").attr("data-price"));

        $secondNum.attr('data-price', numRand2);

        $secondNum.text( $("#secondNum").attr("data-price"));


        //Get the .drop zones
        var drop = $('.drop');

        var draggedItem = null;

        //Add the Event Listener to draggable item "+" symbol
        $('.draggable-item').on('dragstart', function(e){
            draggedItem = jQuery(this);
        }, false);

        drop.on('dragover', cancel);
        drop.on('dragenter', cancel);

        drop.on('drop', function(e){
            //Prevent default browser behaviour
           e.preventDefault(); 

          //Do the math
        var sum = parseInt($("#firstNum").attr("data-price")) + parseInt($("#secondNum").attr("data-price"));

         //add result 
        $('span').html(sum);

         /*alert(sum);*/          

           return false;
        });

    })();
```

Comment: Have you tried http://www.codecademy.com/?

Comment: Please post a complete code example so that we can re-create the issue. Also, a jsFiddle.net example would help.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of code. You can view the full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/W572n/

Comment: Nobody knows why this isn't working in FireFox? I've been trying to figure this out for hours and I can't seem to find a solution. Came across this article http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/#toc-dataTransfer although it is somewhat useful it doesn't really help being that it's referring to native JS and not jQuery library. Any help much appreciated. TY